# vba code to calculate formula that is based on input from other columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 columns with values **A**, **B**, **C** and **D**

I have to create columns E and F

```
Column E = Column C - Column A and
Column F = (ColumnD/ColumnE)*1000
```

Here's the thing, It is a huge data set with 20 or so columns and I need the code to be dynamic...I tried recording a macro but it doesnt help when I move to a another column

Need your help vba experts

I'm new to VBA :(

Comment: Try make it a table by selecting the data and pressing Ctrl+T. Then try what you did again.

Comment: Just enter the formula in column E and F and then copy down.